# Tooltip único em 2 elementos (um corpo e 2 setas)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-3, tooltip

Não sei se o código nativo do `Bootstrap` permite isso para o *tooltip* ou para o *popover*. Tenho 2 links e preciso fazer de alguma forma que seja criado um *tooltip* ou um *popover* que possa unir ambos os links com 2 setas.

```
┌=======┐  ┌=======┐
└===▼===┘  └===▼===┘
  link 1     link 2
```

Basicamente o exemplo acima é um *tooltip* comum, individual para cada link. O que eu preciso é como o modelo abaixo. São links que estão lado a lado.

```
┌==================┐
└===▼==========▼===┘
  link 1     link 2
```

Existe algo nativo que possa manipular para isso, alguma extensão ou outra lib? Pode ate ser manipulação pelo *jQuery* se for possível.

Comment: Nativamente não é possível, as setas do *tooltip* e do *popover* são geradas por uma `<div>`, com classes `tooltip-arrow` e `arrow` respectivamente, com posicionamento absoluto. A manipulação com jQuery me parece a solução mais adequada.